# Imbricated json object value change

Tags: javascript

I have an empty javascript object, and I want to do something like this:

```
this.conflictDetails[this.instanceId][this.modelName][this.entityId] = { solved: true };
```

The problem is that for the modelName I get Cannot read properties of undefined.
I think it is because the empty object this.conflictDetails does not have the property that I m looking for, I wonder how I could write this to work and to be as clear as possible?

The result should look like:

```
{
  'someInstanceId': {
    'someModelName': {
      'some entityId': {
        solved: true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With mu; time instance ids, that hold multiple model names, that have multiple entity Ids

Comment: If you dont know the key values, then you will need to use ```Object.keys``` function and iterate over or else ```this.conflictDetails[this.instanceId] && this.conflictDetails[this.instanceId][this.modelName] && this.conflictDetails[this.instanceId][this.modelName][this.entityId] && this.conflictDetails[this.instanceId][this.modelName] = { solved: true }; ```

Answer (score 0):

check this the '?' operator

```js
let obj = {
  'someInstanceId': {
    'someModelName': {
      'someEntityId': {
        solved: true
      }
    }
  }
};

let value1 = obj.someInstanceId?.someModelName?.someEntityId;
console.log(value1);

// or
value1 = obj["someInstanceId"] ?? {};
value1 = value1["someModelName"] ?? {};
value1 = value1["someEntityId"];
console.log(value1);

let value2 = obj.someInstanceId?.someMissModelName?.someEntityId;
console.log(value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces to define the model of the object, or you can check if every nested object is not null nor undefined.

I would prefer the first option if I use typescript. If not, then i would stick to the not null/undefined option

First we create a model:

```
export interface CustomObject {
  [instanceId: string]: {
    [modelName: string]: {
      [entityId: string]: {
        solved: boolean;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Now that we have a model we can fill an object with data:

We define the object in the .ts file of your component

```
public dataObjects: CustomObject = {
  instance1: {
    basicModel: {
      Entity1: {
        solved: false,
      },
    },
  }
};
```

Now you can have for example a function to change the solved status, I assume that there are several instanceIds, modelNames and entityIds.

```
public resolveObject(
  instanceId: string,
  modelName: string,
  entity: string,
  solved: boolean
) {
  this.dataObjects[instanceId][modelName][entity].solved = solved;
}
```

Now you can call the method with the object details:

```
this.resolveObject('instance1', 'basicModel', 'Entity1', true);
```

After this line is executed the solved will changer from false to true.

I've created a StackBlitz to show you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ibfohk

Comment: This looks like a viable option, but please write that this is Typescript, while the OP has used javascript. I've commented just to avoid confusion for those that are learning one of these languages :)

Comment: Sorry, always happens to me that im watching posts on Angular tag and then I switch to javascript and forgot about it haha